# Language switch with gatsby and WPML

Tags: wordpress, gatsby, multilingual, wpml

I've recently been trying to create a basic multilingual wordpress website using gatsby.

For now, I have been able to fetch my main page and its english translation, as follow :

```
    {
      "node": {
        "wpml_translations": [
          {
            "locale": "fr_FR",
            "wordpress_id": 2,
            "post_title": "Page d’exemple",
            "href": "http://bdr.local/page-d-exemple/"
          }
        ],
        "slug": "example-page",
        "title": "Example page",
        "wordpress_id": 24,
        "wpml_current_locale": "en_US"
      }
    },
```

However, I am missing the slug from the translated page in order to create a proper link to it, and I'd rather not take it from the page url that's given from the url.

Will I have to fire a second graphql request using the ID provided in the wpml_translations, or am I missing something?

Thank you !